# store results of automatic tests and show results in a web UI

Tags: unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I'm looking for a piece (or a set) of software that allows to store the outcome (ok/failed) of an automatic test and additional information (the test protocol to see the exact reason for a failure and the device state at the end of a test run as a compressed archive). The results should be accessible via a web UI.

I don't need fancy pie charts or colored graphs. A simple table is enough. However, the user should be able to filter for specific test runs and/or specific tests. The test runs should have a sane name (like the version of the software that was tested, not just some number).

Currently the build system includes unit tests based on cmake/ctest whose results should be included. Furthermore, integration testing will be done in the future, where the actual tests will run on embedded hardware controlled via network by a shell script or similar. The format of the test results is therefore flexible and could be something like subunit or TAP, if that helps.

I have played around with Jenkins, which is said to be great for automatic tests, but the plugins I tried to make that work don't seem to interact well. To be specific: the test results analyzer plugin doesn't show tests imported with the TAP plugin, and the names of the test runs are just a meaningless build number, although I used the Job Name Setter plugin to set a sensible job name. The filtering options are limited, too.

My somewhat uneducated guess is that I'll stumple about similar issues if I try other random tools of the same class like Jenkins.

Is anyone aware of a solution for my described testing scenario? Lightweight/open source software is preferred.